# why cant i assign a variable to the result of an async call via await?

Tags: dart

I have the following lines, which doesnt work.  It says: *expected ; after await.*

```
import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
http.Response rslt = await http.post(/*...*/);
```

Since `http.post` by definition returns a *Future(Response)*, does `await` not resolve that?  I thought it would.

https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/http/0.11.3%2B3/http/http-library.html

i always thought in a sense, the await, will unwrap the Future object and assign it to whatever... in this case a Response variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the method/function containing this code is missing the `async` modifier.

```
Future someFunc() async {
  import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
  http.Response rslt = await http.post(/*...*/);
}
```

If the function body doesn't have the `async` modifier, `async` is a valid identifier because `async` is not a keyword.

Comment: Oh, you mean the parent function and not the definition

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit tricky that way. `await` only works inside functions marked as `async`.  The called function (`http.post()` in your example) does not actually have to be marked `async`; as long as it returns a `Future`, it should work.

Comment: `http.post()` doesn't even need to return a Future. You can await any expression. Nested `Future`s are flattened and no `Future` at all also gets "flattended".